# Transaction initiation and response

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, remix

When we initiates a transaction(let say by remix using injected web3), we will get response which includes hash of transaction as transaction id which helps to track the transaction. Before this, if the transaction  will fails to broadcast then instantly throws some error message showing transaction failure.

1. Before submitting to network, do transaction is validated locally? and how ?